# Identify if a record is within 1 year in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am trying to identify records that expire within 1 year of today's date. This is the code I have and it doesn't work because I can't add or subtract integers from dates. Can someone assist? I know this is simple.

```
from datetime import date

today = date.today()

mask = (df['[PCW]Contract (Expiration Date)'] <= today + 365)
```

Comment: Can you add some of the dataframe to the question?

Comment: There are years with 366 days. Does that matter?

Comment: @BillHuang no it does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use time deltas.

```
from datetime import timedelta
one_year = timedelta(days=365)
mask = (df['[PCW]Contract (Expiration Date)'] <= today + one_year)
```

Assuming you are using datetime objects in your dataframe.

### UPDATE

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'[PCW]Contract (Expiration Date)' :["2020-01-21T02:37:21", '2021-01-21T02:37:21', '2022-01-21T02:37:21']})
s = pd.to_datetime(df['[PCW]Contract (Expiration Date)'])
one_year = np.timedelta64(365,'D')
today = np.datetime64('today')
mask = s <= today + one_year
mask
```

Output

```
0     True
1     True
2    False
Name: [PCW]Contract (Expiration Date), dtype: bool
```

Comment: I get this error: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date

Comment: You can also use [`pd.Timdelta(days=365)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html).

Comment: @Ch3steR I get the same error

Comment: I assume that the type of df['[PCW]...'] is numpy.datetime64. Then you should use one_year = numpy.timedelta64(365,'D')

Comment: @Oddaspa sorry this will probably help. the dates came as strings, i formatted them to datetime with pd.to_datetime.

Comment: I updated the answer to contain an example.